# doctrine 2 query builder and join tables

Tags: doctrine-orm, left-join, query-builder

I'm trying to get all comments for each post in my home page

```
return 
$this->createQueryBuilder('c')
->select('c')
->from('Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Commentaire' ,'c')                
->leftJoin('a.comments' ,'c')->getQuery()->getResult() ;
```

but I'm getting this error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 58 near '.comments c,': Error:
Identification Variable a used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

PS : The mapping is correct because I can see the page article with its comments.

Comment: i found out how guys here

`return  $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
->select('a ,c')
->leftJoin('a.comments' ,'c')
->getQuery()
->getResult() ;`

Comment: can you pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115165/doctrine-inner-left-join-two-tables I tried you solution but its not working fo me..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In case this is still giving you problems, here is your query using the syntax found in the examples in the Doctrine 2.1 documentation.

I'm assuming your query resides in a custom repository method, and that 'a' is an abbreviation for 'Article'.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select(array('a', 'c'))
   ->from('Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article', 'a')
   ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'c');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();

return $results;
```

Comment: with reference to this question i am trying to solve my problem but i am facing issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115165/doctrine-inner-left-join-two-tables