# ORM QueryBuilder with Entity subobjects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities: author and person.

In the author entity, there is a person field which is in fact the person object:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="submission_authors")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $person;
```

Now, in the repository: AuthorRepository, I would like to search for some authors by their firstname. To do this, I need to access the person object for the corresponding author ans look on the person's firstname.

I tryed:

```
 public function searchAuthors($q)
{
    $authQB = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
    ->select('a')
    ->where("a.person.firstname LIKE '%".$q."%'");

    return $authQB->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But the problem is that I am geting an error:

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 78: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_LIKE, got '.'
```

Coud you please help me on how to resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to access your `person` relation like this:

```
$authQB = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
    ->select('a')
    ->leftJoin('a.person', 'p')
   //...
```

To learn a bit more about query builder and joint tables:

- This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031321/doctrine-2-query-builder-and-join-tables) post.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$authQB = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
    ->select('a')
    ->innerJoin('a.person', 'p')
    ->where('p.firstname LIKE :myStuff')
    ->setParameter('myStuff', '%'.$q.'%');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not there. Igf you take a look on thee error message from symfony, doctrine is not expecting a dot (".") after the a.person. There should be another possibility to access the person object.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer. I don't think that we can, in doctrine, wright things like `rootAlias.relationship.field`, you actually have make an inner/left join.

Comment: Yes, that's what @Patt suggested me. Thank you