# Doctrine2: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::field()

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a query with the doctrine query builder:

```
public function searchAuthors($q)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Author')
    ->field('person.firstname')->equals('test');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I am getting :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::field() in ... on line 18
```

The field() method is from the doctrine documentation webpage. Could you please help me to resolve that.

Thank you.

Comment: Same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560575/orm-querybuilder-with-entity-subobjects), you need to use left join.

Comment: Thank you Patt, but my question was more about why the field() method is undefined...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`field()` exists only in [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php#L365-L376) (to use it see [here](https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html?highlight=field%28%29#getting-single-result)) not in [Doctrine 2 ORM](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php).