# Doctrine INNER/LEFT JOIN two tables

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

[I am learning from this Question but facing issues with many operations in between:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031321/doctrine-2-query-builder-and-join-tables)

[doctrine 2 query builder and join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031321/doctrine-2-query-builder-and-join-tables)

Below is my Questions. I am looking for help in my previous question too.. Thanks for those who helped me in solving the issues.

I am creating a big Query in Doctrine 2.3, The operations are not familiar to me.But I learnt with the help of many persons.  Currently I am facing issue with Inner Joint between 3 tables.

My Joint:

```
SELECT *
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN source AS s ON u.user_source_fk=s.source_id
LEFT JOIN area AS a ON s.source_node_fk = a.area_id;
```

The above Query is what I am trying to convert in Doctrine.

I tried to give the query as like this but it is not working:

```
SELECT a FROM Ipf\Model\User u LEFT JOIN Ipf\Model\Sources ON u.user_source_fk=s.source_id LEFT JOIN Ipf\Model\Area aa ON s.source_node_fk = aa.area_id;
```

How My Original Query will be:

## 1 Doctrine JOIN Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN source AS s ON u.user_source_fk=s.source_id
LEFT JOIN area AS a ON s.source_node_fk = a.area_id;
```

+

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
(`user_name` like '%TOM%' OR `user_name` like '%AN%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-02-31 23:59:59') OR
NOT ( --NOR
   (`user_name` like '%PHP%' OR `user_name` like '%BA%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-02-01 00:00:00' and '2013-03-31 23:59:59') OR
   (`user_name` like '%SUN%' OR `user_name` like '%MOON%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' and '2013-04-31 23:59:59')
) OR
NOT ( --NAND
   (`user_name` like '%RAJ%' OR `user_name` like '%MUTH%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' and '2013-06-31 23:59:59') AND
   (`user_name` like '%BAG%' OR `user_name` like '%LAP%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and '2013-07-31 23:59:59')
)
```

I want to do Inner Joint to the Query with the above Query that is Inner Joint with Operators [Refer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046926/multiple-query-in-doctrine-with-nand-nor-not-and-operators)[Multiple Query in Doctrine with NAND,NOR,NOT,AND Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046926/multiple-query-in-doctrine-with-nand-nor-not-and-operators)

How to Join the tables and execute the Query?

## 2 Doctrine Query Generation:

```
$qry = $this->manager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from($this->entity, 'e')
        ->select('e');


// (`user_name` like '%TOM%' OR `user_name` like '%AN%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-02-31 23:59:59')
$expr1 = $qry->expr()->andX(
    $qry->expr()->orX(
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%TOM%'), 
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%AN%')
    ),
    $qry->expr()->between('e.login_datetime', '2013-02-01 00:00:00', '2013-02-31 23:59:59')
);

//(`user_name` like '%PHP%' OR `user_name` like '%BA%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-02-01 00:00:00' and '2013-03-31 23:59:59')

$expr2a = $qry->expr()->andX(
    $qry->expr()->orX(
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%PHP%'), 
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%BA%')
    ),
    $qry->expr()->between('e.login_datetime', ''2013-02-01 00:00:00'', '2013-03-31 23:59:59')
);

// (`user_name` like '%SUN%' OR `user_name` like '%MOON%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' and '2013-04-31 23:59:59')
$expr2b = $qry->expr()->andX(
    $qry->expr()->orX(
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%SUN%'), 
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%MOON%')
    ),
    $qry->expr()->between('e.login_datetime', '2013-03-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-31 23:59:59')
);

// combine expr2a and expr2b with OR as $expr2

$expr2 = $qry->expr()->orX($expr2a, $expr2b);


// (`user_name` like '%RAJ%' OR `user_name` like '%MUTH%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' and '2013-06-31 23:59:59')

$expr3a = $qry->expr()->andX(
    $qry->expr()->orX(
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%RAJ%'), 
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%MUTH%')
    ),
    $qry->expr()->between('e.login_datetime', ''2013-04-01 00:00:00'', '2013-06-31 23:59:59')
);

// (`user_name` like '%BAG%' OR `user_name` like '%LAP%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and '2013-07-31 23:59:59')
$expr3b = $qry->expr()->andX(
    $qry->expr()->orX(
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%BAG%'), 
       $qry->expr()->like('e.user_name', '%LAP%')
    ),
    $qry->expr()->between('e.login_datetime', '2013-05-01 00:00:00', '2013-07-31 23:59:59')
);

// combine expr2a and expr2b with OR as $expr2

$expr3 = $qry->expr()->andX($expr3a, $expr3b);


// final query essentially WHERE expr1 OR NOT(expr2) OR NOT(expr3)
$qry->where($expr1)
    ->or($qry->expr()->not($expr2))
    ->or($qry->expr()->not($expr3));
```

How can I Modify to Achieve the Above Query with JOIN Operation?

Can some one help me to solve my issue. Its nightmare for me in doctrine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex part of you query is actually the `WHERE` so you should be able to just add the joins with little issue.

```
$qry = $this->manager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('e', 's', 'a'))
        ->from($this->entity, 'e')
        ->leftJoin('e.sources', 's')
        ->leftJoin('s.node', 'a');
```

And then you would do the rest of your query logic as is pretty much.

The one thing that needs to be mentioned is that in DQL you are dealing with Entities and their properties as opposed to tables and columns.

So in my example `e.sources` needs to be the mapped property name for the `UserSource` entity/collection on your `User` entity. Likewise, `s.node` needs to be the mapped property name of the `Area` entity/collection on `UserSource`.

Comment: It also means that I need to joint the two tables in XML Mapping or just I can create the query and run?

Comment: I saw may joints in Doctrine One-to-one, One-to-many, many-to-many, Bi-directional? Is there any thing DO I want to change?

Comment: I dunno you didnt post your model... that would be necessary to evaluate it. But typically yes, if you are using the ORM then you should define the appropriate mappings. If you are just using DBAL then that is a different story.

Comment: I am woring with any existing application which was created by Zend/Doctrine Experts.. and they are using many function which are confusing to me.. but I didnt come across any DBAL till now.. My Modules for your reference the XML mapping which still I am facing issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917684/doctrine-xml-mapping-two-tables

Comment: Also the above query should find the number of result found with limit in same query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079748/doctrine-query-to-find-total-number-of-result-in-mysql-with-limit

Comment: can some one help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211636/update-text-field-with-issue-in-doctrine